# Speed up clojure startup time with nailgun

Tags: shell, clojure, startup, nailgun

Every now and then I think it would be nice to use `clojure` for *shell scripts*, but a startup time of about 900ms is way too slow. I'd then <strike>google</strike>[startpage](https://startpage.com/) for "nailgun clojure", but the only results that show up are for special cases like vimclojure. That's when I, pretending not to have time, turn to more `awk`ward languages that start up faster.

So, how can `nailgun` be used to speed up the startup time of clojure?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**Debian**

Do the following once:

```
apt-get install nailgun                          # install nailgun
java -server -jar /usr/share/java/nailgun.jar&   # run nailgun server
ng-nailgun ng-cp /usr/share/java/clojure-1.4.jar # add clj to classpath
```

Now that the server is running and configured, you can run your clojure scripts on it:

```
ng-nailgun clojure.main path/to/myscript.clj
```

In my case, startup time of the actual script went down to 80ms, compared to 900ms without nailgun.

To **make running the actual script more convenient**, create an executable file `ng-clojure` containing the following line, and put it somewhere in your path:

```
ng-nailgun clojure.main "$@"
```

In your *clojure shell script*, add this as the first line:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ng-clojure
```

Then make the clojure shell script executable and run it like

```
path/to/myscript.clj
```

**OSX**

```
brew install nailgun
ng-server 
ng ng-cp ~/.m2/repository/org/clojure/clojure/1.5.1/clojure-1.5.1.jar
```

Then execute your script as above.

**Update**: Having used it for a while, it doesn't seem to work flawlessly. Sometimes I'm getting **random errors** that don't occur when running without nailgun, and sometimes there seems to be a **memory leak** that makes the nailgun JVM consume all memory over time, eventually making the system swap to disk. Haven't memory profiled this yet, but wanted to add this heads-up.

Comment: Massive! Someone should share this on a Planet Clojure blog.

Comment: Wouldn't get problems with code clashes when trying to run different things on one java server? Or have I misunderstood something?

Comment: @rvirding I'm not sure what you mean by "code clashes", but I wouldn't be surprised if this didn't work 100%. There might for example be issues with things like static global state.

Comment: The likely cause of the memory leak is that Clojure will generate many new classes at runtime, and the jvm's gc is not as adept with cleaning up permgen / garbage classes as it is with normal data

Comment: @noisesmith It's a while back now, but I'd be surprised if I had, during the lifetime of nailgun, created what amounts to gigabytes of class files - garbage collected or not.