# How do I run a leiningen generated class using nailgun?

Tags: java, clojure, nailgun

I've written a program in Clojure and used leiningen to compile it into **something.jar**, **something-standalone.jar** and a folder containing all the classes, such as **core.class**, **core$_main.class** and all the other good stuff.

The .jar files run fine but I need to cut the jvm startup overhead.

**How do I run it with nailgun?**

Comment: nailgun only makes sense if every Clojure program you run has the same versions of its deps. Also, nailgun won't eliminate the Clojure startup time, which takes much longer than the JVM's startup, because Clojure can't run without bootstrapping its compiler. Consider `grench` for a setup that will actually improve Clojure startup time (though it shares the same problem that all apps will need to use the same version of any libs used).

Comment: Also, this question is a duplicate, and the top answer plainly indicates that Clojure and nailgun don't actually work very well together. Some of the errors caused will have to do with the fact that Clojure generates many classes at runtime, and these will not be shared between the instances you load up. [previously answered here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19107683/speed-up-clojure-startup-time-with-nailgun)